# Shouldn't the wordpress database be Normalized?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, database-design, database-normalization

I just started learning the custom wordpress queries and came across the wordpress database. I was just astonished to see that the database wasn't normalized. I mean it'd be okay to use such a structure (i.e. having redundant data) in case when you haven't immense data but what if you have a large data. It would have less performance, wouldn't it? My question is:

Why would such a reputed product use an denormalized database? Are there any specific reasons behind?

[image]

Comment: What is the type of this column?  Is it `ENUM` perchance?

Comment: What's "un-normalized" about this? I do not see any redundant data in your example.

Comment: Please have a good look at the column named `post_status`, having repeated data i.e. 'publish' (3 times in this figure), `inherit` (3 times in this figure).

Comment: That's not redundancy. Redundancy is when the same **semantic** data is in different tables. If, in your case, the column "post_data" also appears in other tables. You can mostly derive redundancy from the database schema, not from the actual data. And having `post_status` per post is not very redundant.

Comment: @KamranAhmed had there been, say `1`, instead of `publish`, would that be okay? Now, say publish was some kind of esoteric `post_status` then would you say the same thing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The benefit of storing 'publish' as a string rather than a surrogate key reference to a lookup table is to avoid a `JOIN` to the lookup table.

The example you give, storing the word 'publish' on multiple rows, is not itself denormalization.  You may be confusing normalization with the use of surrogate keys.  These are two independent things.  Surrogate keys (auto-increment "id" primary key) has nothing to do with normalization.

The reason to denormalize data is to give *certain* queries better performance.

Any such optimization comes with risks, as you note.

- You may have data anomalies because of the redundant data storage.
- The size of storage may increase (though a single WordPress instance isn't likely to store a lot).
- Different queries may have worse performance.

The best practice for denormalization is to be certain you know which queries need to have best performance, and then to write code to handle the extra work to ensure data integrity when you have redundant storage.

Comment: You can eliminate these data anomalies with a foreign key reference to a table that stores the values 'publish', 'inherit', 'trash', etc. (You already knew that. OP might not.)